# What legal proof is valid for a user to complain under an online privacy policy

Tags: privacy, website, online-piracy, indian-constitutional-law

Now a days most of website like Bank,Social media,Financial service apps and almost all online service) when we signup or create online a/c or use some online services we need to select privacy policy before registration.

My concern is what we can do If in future they work against their own policy and change their policy without informing us **(As it just a static online content and no body can track like what is changed)** They can easily deny like this is the policy from beginning.

How can we legally proof that the policy we accepted was different?.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Archive (IA) routinely takes snapshots of websites, indeed of much of the content on the web. Their service can be used to demonstrate the content of the site on the date of any such snapshot. They also have a procedure by which anyone can request a snapshot of any web page at any time. Although they do not guarantee to comply with such requests, they often do. It has become common practice to use the IA to establish, in court cases, the content of a web site on a particular date.

Their [FAQ page](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360004651732-Using-The-Wayback-Machine) says:

> **How can I get pages authenticated from the Wayback Machine? How can use the pages in court?**
>
> The Wayback Machine tool was not designed for legal use. We do have a legal request policy found at our legal page. Please read through the entire policy before contacting us with your questions. We do have a standard affidavit as well as a FAQ section for lawyers. We would prefer that before you contact us for such services, you see if the other side will stipulate instead. We do not have an in-house legal staff, so this service takes away from our normal duties. Once you have read through our policy, if you still have questions, please contact us for more information.

I recall reading the IA FAQ for lawyers in the past, but am not able to find it just now.

---

Note that even if you establish what their policy was when you signed up, you will still need to determine what actual rights this gives you. Most privacy policies are carefully written so that they will not give users more rights their the site owners choose. And n=many such policies contain language such as "the site may change this policy at any time without notice. Continued use of the site constitutes consent to the revised policy." Of course, if the EU GDPR applies, such a disclaimer may not be valid.

Comment: The Way Back Machine/Internet Archive isn't fool proof tho - if the current owners of the website puts up a robots.txt which disallows indexing of that particular page, the WBM/IA removes it from their archive, including all historical copies.

Comment: My understanding is that they actually retain such pages but block access to them. But it is definitely true that the IA is not foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous notarisation approaches you can take, including printing out the agreement when you accept it, taking it to a [notary public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary_public) or solicitors and having them officially notarise it.  This may cost you money, but it gives you a document with a date, time and official seal of a notary public on it.

There are other ways also, such as taking a cryptographic hash of the text contents of the agreement at the time you agree to it, and then using a public blockchain system like Bitcoin to [include that hash into the blockchain](https://cryptonews.com/news/a-simple-way-to-immortalize-your-message-on-the-bitcoin-bloc-3014.htm) - this is proof that the text you can present was the actual text at that point in time, as changing a public blockchains history is extremely difficult (but not impossible, although it would require significant ability to do, along the lines of a state actor for Bitcoin for example).

Answer (score -3):

Keep a copy of the policy you agreed to.